# Deconstructing the basis of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was given this matrix and was asked to find a basis for it.

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & a+b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$

After some looking I realized that it was the matrices

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Which is not too hard to see. But I was wondering if there is a more concrete method for unwrapping the matrix into it's basis matrices when the situation becomes more complicated and it's not as easy to see.

Comment: I think you missed $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\ 1&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The method you describe doesn't exist, primarily because you can choose an unlimited number of bases for a space. Consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ -- we generally use the standard $e_1, e_2$ basis configuration, but any two linearly independent vectors would suffice. In the same way, you'll have to pick your basis of $\mathbb{R^{2x2}}$ first, and then break down your matrix in terms of such a basis, for which *any* element in the space can be expressed as a linear combination of basic elements.

Also, the basis you describe is wrong, since there is no possible way of adding + scaling those matrices together to recoup your original one. Also, the dimensionality of $\mathbb{R^{2x2}}$ is four. Try looking at the standard basis, with 1's in each position of the matrix.

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo. I typed the second basis vector wrong.